# Getting all primes between 0 - n

Tags: c#, primes

Is there a faster way to get all primes between 0 - n?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Numerics;

namespace myPrime
{
    public class simplePrimer
    {
        public List<BigInteger> primeList;

        public void findVersion(BigInteger goal)
        {
            BigInteger number = 3;
            primeList = new List<BigInteger> { 2 };

            try
            {
                while (number < goal)
                {
                    if (isPrime(number))
                        primeList.Add(number);
                    number += 2;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i found " + primeList.Count + " Prime Numbers");
                Console.WriteLine(primeList.Last() + "was the last Prime");
            }
        }  

        private bool isPrime(BigInteger number)
        {
            foreach (BigInteger prime in primeList)
                if (number % prime == 0)
                    return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like:

```
primer.findVersion1(999999);
```

Comment: You're going to want to find a non naïve prime algorithm. Check out this answer on Stackoverflow that will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220907/efficient-algorithm-to-get-primes-between-two-large-numbers

Comment: To speed it up a lot, especially for a large goal, don't check each prime in primeList in the isPrime method but only primes that are less then the square root of the number.

Comment: @IvoBeckers why do i only need to check primes which are less  then the square root of the number, wouldn't i miss some Primes?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, Imagine a divider of a number that is larger than square root of the number. if you then divide the number by that divider you would always get a number smaller then the square root of the number. That number would also be a divider (logically) and would be encountered earlier then.

Comment: btw made a small mistake, it shoud be smaller then **or equal to** the square root

Comment: @IvoBeckers mhh square root doesn't make really sense to me, because the closes nummer to `n` we check could be `3*x`  which isn't close to the square root IMHO

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri

Comment: @IvoBeckers haha now i get it after creating an example :D

Comment: Do you realize that `BigInteger` is much slower than `int` and `long`?

Comment: @Gabe sure but you can hold bigger number with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For relatively small numbers, the best method is very likely the [Sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Here's a method I wrote a few years ago that implements it. A useful thing to do is to use a BitArray; it will save a lot of space. It also skips even numbers to save even more space. I also made it return each number in sequence instead of returning a List.

Finding prime numbers up to int.MaxValue takes about 45 seconds (and uses +/- 130Mb of memory). Using 1 million as bound will be lightning fast, though. It can be done faster still, but the code would become more complex.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Primes(int bound)
{
    if (bound < 2) yield break;
    //The first prime number is 2
    yield return 2;

    BitArray composite = new BitArray((bound - 1) / 2);
    int limit = ((int)(Math.Sqrt(bound)) - 1) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (composite[i]) continue;
        //The first number not crossed out is prime
        int prime = 2 * i + 3;
        yield return prime;
        //cross out all multiples of this prime, starting at the prime squared
        for (int j = (prime * prime - 2) >> 1; j < composite.Count; j += prime) {
            composite[j] = true;
        }
    }
    //The remaining numbers not crossed out are also prime
    for (int i = limit; i < composite.Count; i++) {
        if (!composite[i]) yield return 2 * i + 3;
    }
}
```

For larger numbers, you need more advanced techniques. A popular one is the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Comment: would you mind checking out my version and letting me know what you think?  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56500/18427

Answer (score 8):

Leaving aside the algorithm there are a number of points about the code

**Naming**
Pascal casing is standard for C# - `SimplePrimer` and `FindVersion` as opposed to `simplePrimer` and `findVersion`.
`FindVersion` seems unconnected to the functionality.

**Structure**
public fields are generally frowned upon.  If it needs to be part of the interface, make it a Property so that the implementation can be changed if needed.
Having a separate 'return' as PrimeList seems overly complicated. There is no strong reason for not having `List<BigInteger> GetPrimes(BigInteger goal)`
Looking at the code, I cannot see anything obvious that might throw an exception that might be caught by the `catch` (perhaps an out of range on the BigInteger?) Is it needed? 
As a shape I would push for any output to be external to the function. Have the calling code catch errors or report results. It makes unit testing a lot simpler

Comment: +1 I totally agree with all your points so will change that. The naming of my methode `findVersion`is because i had multiple versions of `find`. But in the end i was really just looking for a performance improvement so i can't accept your answer, sry.